# Where to find the tags used in theme short codes? As well as the general tags used in pyroCMS?

Tags: themes, shortcode, pyrocms

I was wondering where to find the tags to type to take advantage of shortcodes programmed in themes. Many themes have them, such as the one below. However I can never find the information required to make use of them in the read me's or on site documentation. Which makes using them impossible for me. Is there a specific html, css, or php file that is consistent to each theme and shows them?

Given the lack of write ups on what tags to use suggests that theme creators expect people to know which file to find them in.

https://www.pyrocms.com/uploads/default/store/listings/11-25-2012_9-41-20_PM.png

https://www.pyrocms.com/uploads/default/store/listings/11-25-2012_9-41-20_PM.png

On a more PyroCMS rather than theme specific note, is there a list of all tags and their uses? Such as {{ settings:site_name }}, or the page body tag. Every link I have found to a list says that the list has been moved.

Thank you for your time once again.

Answer (score 2):

Open up your file directory and navigate to:

```
path/to/your/files/system/cms/plugins/theme.php
```

Each one you can use is listed here along with an example in the function description. Each plugin in this folder is lined out the same way (files, session, asset, etc). You should be able to view each one and play with how to incorporate them into your project.

Edit: Also, you can find more information here: http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/plugins
Notice that this is specific to version 2.1. If you are not using 2.1, in the top navigation add click on documentation and then select your version.